# mysql server: What is the Difference between "Stop Server" and "Bring Offline"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I could see  `Stop Server` and `Bring Offline` in **mysql workbench**.

[image]

I hope both are used to stop the services but still confused in difference between both in terms of ***when to use Stop Server and Bring Offline?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Stop server** just stops the mysql process

**Offline mode** is a new feature introduced in MySQL 5.7.5, that basically throws out all users except DBAs :

> MySQL Server now supports an “offline mode” with these
>   characteristics:
>
> - Connected client users who do not have the SUPER privilege are disconnected on the next request, with an appropriate error.
>     Disconnection includes terminating running statements and releasing
>     locks. Such clients also cannot initiate new connections, and receive
>     an appropriate error.
> - Connected client users who have the SUPER privilege are not disconnected, and can initiate new connections to manage the server.
> - Replication slave threads are permitted to keep applying data to the server.
>
> Only users who have the SUPER privilege can control offline mode. To
>   put a server in offline mode, change the value of the new offline_mode
>   system variable from OFF to ON. To resume normal operations, change
>   offline_mode from ON to OFF. In offline mode, clients that are refused
>   access receive an ER_SERVER_OFFLINE_MODE error.

Source : [Changes in MySQL 5.7.5 (2014-09-25, Milestone 15)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-5.html)